# How to do `[Func[int[], int]]` in Powershell? (PowerShell 7) (Func Delegate Type Parameter)

Tags: c#, powershell, generics

It appears that one can do `[Func[int, int[]]]` but not `[Func[int[], int]]` in powershell.

What's the correct syntax if I want to do `[Func[int[], int]]`?

As a reference, below are the outputs:

- `[Func[int, int]] | Format-Table -Hide`: `` True     True     Func`2                                   System.MulticastDelegate ``
- `[Func[int, int[]]] | Format-Table -Hide`: `` True     True     Func`2                                   System.MulticastDelegate ``
- `[Func[int[], int]] | Format-Table -Hide`: `InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [Func].`

Comment: Correct syntax would be `[System.Func[[int[]], int]]`

Comment: You are right, `[Func[[int[]], int]]` works as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're seeing a *bug***, present in both Windows PowerShell (where it will *not* be fixed) and in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.2.x* - it is **fixed in PowerShell v7.3+**

- See [GitHub issue #18686](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18686)

The **workaround**, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) shows in a comment, is to enclose the embedded *array* type reference in `[...]` - even though this *shouldn't be necessary*:

```bash
# Note the [...] enclosure around int[]
# No longer needed in PS v7.3+
[Func[[int[]], int]]
```